# FFmpeg: Recording Screen and Webcam (in custom location) with an Image or watermark

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, watermark

Thank you so much for checking out my post, I'm still new to ffmpeg but I am really interested in experimenting with it, yet I'm facing the following **filter_complex** problem:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -f dshow -rtbufsize 600M -i video="virtual-screen-camera-input":audio="audio-input-device"
       -f dshow -rtbufsize 700M -i video="webcam-input-device"
       -i image.png
       -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=1536:864:0:0[cropped];[cropped]pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[scaledagain];[scaledagain]scale=1536x864[unscaled];[unscaled]scale=1536:-2[preWebCam];[1:v]hflip[webcamflipped];[webcamflipped]scale=320:240[cutout];[preWebCam][cutout]overlay=1293:443" 
       -c:a aac -strict experimental -ab 128k -ac 1 -ar 44100 -bt 500k 
       -c:v libx264 -x264-params -preset ultrafast -framerate 30 output.flv
```

Expected output: Cropped Screen with an image (Top Left) and a webcam on top of it, the webcam can be in any custom location I choose to put it at.

Real output: image.png is not appearing in the desired location (Top Left)

[image: Output]

Any form of help would be very appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't overlaid the image onto the video. Overlay it after the webcam has been overlaid.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -f dshow -rtbufsize 600M -i video="virtual-screen-camera-input":audio="audio-input-device"
       -f dshow -rtbufsize 700M -i video="webcam-input-device"
       -i image.png
       -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=1536:864:0:0[preWebCam];[1:v]hflip,scale=320:240[cutout];[preWebCam][cutout]overlay=1293:443[preWM];[preWM][2]overlay=10:10" 
       -c:a aac -strict experimental -ab 128k -ac 1 -ar 44100 -bt 500k 
       -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast output.flv
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, I really appreciate how you answer almost all ffmpeg questions, like woah!